# PHP if else echo issue

Tags: php, indentation

I've basically completed my change password form. I just have one issue. When a user wants to change their password it asks for 'Current Password', 'New Password' and 'New password again'. So here's my error: when I enter 'Current Password' and it's right in the database, and then I hit submit, nothing shows up in the 'errors' if you will. I want it to basically show: 'Please fill out the whole form'

Image 1:

[image]

Image 2:

[image]

On image 2 it should display under home 'Please fill out the whole form'

Here's my code:

```
<?php
session_start();



$username = $_SESSION['sess_user'];

    echo '<div class="search1"><h2>'.$username.'</h2><div class="search12"><h2><a href="index.php">Home</a></h2></p></div></div>';


    if (isset($_SESSION['sess_user']))
    {
        //user is logged in

        if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            //start changing password
            //check fields

            $oldpassword = md5($_POST['oldpassword']);
            $newpassword = md5($_POST['newpassword']);


            $repeatnewpassword = md5($_POST['repeatnewpassword']);


            //check password against db
            include('../includes/config.php');

            $queryget = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM login WHERE username='$username'") or die ("change password failed");
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryget);
            $oldpassworddb = $row['password'];

            //check passwords
            if ($oldpassword==$oldpassworddb && !empty($_POST['oldpassword'])) 

             else {echo "<div class='results'>Please fill out the whole form</div><div class='successmate'><h2><p><a href='changepassword.php'><br><br></a></p></h2></div>";}

            {



                if (isset($_POST['repeatnewpassword']) AND isset($_POST['newpassword']) AND $_POST['newpassword'] != '') {
                    if ($newpassword==$repeatnewpassword)
                    {
                        $querychange = mysql_query("UPDATE login SET password='$newpassword' WHERE   username='$username'");
                        echo "<div class='successmate'><br><br><br><br><hr>Password has been changed!</hr></div><div class='successmate'><br><hr><br><h2><p><a href='index2.php'><br><br></a></p></h2></div>";
                    }
                    else {echo "<div class='results'>new password(s) dont match</div><div class='successmate'><br><br><h2><p><a href='changepassword.php'>try again?</a></p></h2></div>";}

                }




            }
            else {echo "<div class='results'>current password doesnt match</div><div class='successmate'><h2><p><a href='changepassword.php'><br><br>Try again?</a></p></h2></div>";}





            if (isset($_POST['email']) AND $_POST['email'] != '') {
                $querychange = mysql_query("UPDATE login SET email='$email' WHERE   username='$username'");
                echo "<div class='successmate'><br><br><br><br><hr>Your email has been changed</hr></div><div class='successmate'><br><hr><br><h2><p><a href='index2.php'><br><br></a></p></h2></div>";
            }}


        else
        {

            echo"
        <form class='search1' action='changepassword.php' method='POST'>
        <label>Current Password:*</label> <input type='password' id='password' name='oldpassword' required><p>
        <label>New Password:*</label> <input type='password' id='password' name='newpassword'><p>
        <label>Repeat New Password:*</label> <input type='password'  name='repeatnewpassword'><p>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' class='submit' value='submit'><br><br><br>
        <h2><p><a href='index2.php'>Back</a></p></h2>
        </form>
        ";


        }}
    else
        die ("You must be logged in to change your password");


    ?>
```

Comment: `MD5` is cryptographically broken. Look at using `password_hash()` available in PHP 5.5+. There's a shim you can use for earlier versions too.

Comment: Man this is hard to read. First, why are you checking if md5 of oldpassword == md5 in db and them whether oldpassword is "empty"? Also  why are you assuming sess_user exists, dumping the results (leading to a possible XSS attack vector), and then checking if it's empty? Also, why are you injecting the username (taken blindly from the session) without escaping it at all into the SQL statement leading to a SQL injection vulnerability? I seriously was trying to figure out what you were doing to answer your actual question, but this is a mess to get through.

Comment: If you're building your quries from scratch, at least use http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php on all variables (in this case, username and email). Otherwise anyone with any inclination do do so can take over the entire database. (I am still trying to figure out what you're doing here and where you went wrong in terms of logic; this is just a fyi).

Comment: This code is full of **severe** problems. You urgently need to read a [guide on PHP best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/) with extra attention paid to [password hashing procedures](http://www.phptherightway.com/#password_hashing). I'd also **strongly encourage** you to pick up a 
[development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) which already has an [authentication system](http://laravel.com/docs/security) built-in so you don't have to write your own. Writing code from the ground up is very hard.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in your code formatting.

As much as I understood from your code, this portion:

```
        //check passwords
        if ($oldpassword==$oldpassworddb && !empty($_POST['oldpassword'])) 

         else {echo "<div class='results'>Please fill out the whole form</div><div class='successmate'><h2><p><a href='changepassword.php'><br><br></a></p></h2></div>";}

        {
```

seems to be syntactically messed up.

You need to re-arrange and clean up your code in the following way:

```
       <?php
       session_start();

           //opening if and other stuff you'll do here

           //check passwords and your code correction done here
           if ($oldpassword==$oldpassworddb && !empty($_POST['oldpassword'])) 
           {

               if (isset($_POST['repeatnewpassword']) AND isset($_POST['newpassword']) AND $_POST['newpassword'] != '') 
               {
                   if ($newpassword==$repeatnewpassword)
                   {
                        $querychange = mysql_query("UPDATE login SET password='$newpassword' WHERE   username='$username'");
                        echo "<div class='successmate'><br><br><br><br><hr>Password has been changed!</hr></div><div class='successmate'><br><hr><br><h2><p><a href='index2.php'><br><br></a></p></h2></div>";
                   }
                   else 
                   {
                       echo "<div class='results'>new password(s) dont match</div><div class='successmate'><br><br><h2><p><a href='changepassword.php'>try again?</a></p></h2></div>";//I removed an extra curly brace here

                   }

               }
               else 
               {
                   echo "<div class='results'>Please fill out the whole form</div><div class='successmate'><h2><p><a href='changepassword.php'><br><br></a></p></h2></div>";
               }
           }


           else 
           {
               echo "<div class='results'>current password doesnt match</div><div class='successmate'><h2><p><a href='changepassword.php'><br><br>Try again?</a></p></h2></div>";
           }


          //do your rest of the work here and end your opening if


?>
```

Honestly, your code looks aweful. One of the signs of a good developer is that he/she makes the code readable, and one of the ways you make your code readable is to follow proper indentation in blocks of code. All your if-else blocks look terrible, you don't seem to care at all about indenting them. The result? You can see for yourself. You code's all messed up, and I had a hard time understanding your if-else blocks, where they started and where they ended. You should go through the following link very seriously: http://www.riedquat.de/prog/style

Comment: @Crescent Moon, It didn't seem to work, gave me 'unexpected else'

Comment: @Sarah Did you really follow the indentation properly and as I've shown you? You must have 4 whitespaces below your curly brace and then write your code. The problem is definitely with indentation. You may have messed up with indentation again in your email and other stuff downwards.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 Where's the problem bro? It looks alright to me.

Comment: English is not my first language either bro. :) Ok. Erm ... ... no ... I don't have an extra  closing `}` before my ending else. That is the closing `}` of my very first `if`. Please check out.

Comment: @All, I edited my answer. Please take a look. Problem was not in the last else, rather in an inside else.

Answer (score 0):

There's flows of logic that are wrong here...

You say...
`if ($oldpassword==$oldpassworddb && !empty($_POST['oldpassword'])) else { ... } { ... }`
... which doesn't make sense. If something is, then do this, else do that should be the statement.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 Gotcha. I read the OP wrong initially myself. Did multiple double-takes :).

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 Crescent Moon is on it :). They're not being particularly nice though... but I wouldn't have been either.

Comment: There may be further problems inside her code. I just focused on her if-else blocks, as primarily I detected logic problem around these messed up nightmare of code blocks.

Comment: @Crescent Moon Her problem, beyond all the other major stuff, is that she's not checking to see if `repeatnewpassword` was submitted as a condition of showing the "need more info" message.

Comment: She has added a "new password(s) don't match" message in her else block for that.

Comment: @CrescentMoon That's only the case in your cleaned up version. In her's, that never happens. Anyhow, I'm done. It's a mess and making my head hurt.